# I FUBAR'd the IP, subnet, and VLAN settings. Now how to access managed switch?

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, subnet, dell-powerconnect

I have a Dell powerconnect 2748. I think I have done messed it up though when setting it up because so far I have not been able to access the webconfig of the switch after I changed some settings I shouldn't have. Here's all of the configurations that I can remember:

> - ports 1 & 2 are set as a LAG group and the LAG group is an untagged member of VLAN 2 with a PVID = 2 on both ports
> - ports 3-24 are untagged members of VLAN 2 with PVID = 2 on all
> - ports 25-44 are untagged members of VLAN 3 with PVID = 3 on all ports
> - ports 45-47 are untagged members of VLAN 1 with PVID = 1 on all ports
>     (Default settings)
> - port 48 is tagged member of VLAN 1, 2, and 3 with PVID = 1

The last thing I did was set the switch's IP address. I set it to the following:

```
IP: 192.168.254.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.252
Gateway: 192.168.254.1
```

My goal was to create a subnet that only contained the switch's IP and the router's IP. I thought the /30 subnet would only allow 2 routable address: 2^(32-30) = 4, 1 network address, 1 broadcast address, and 2 host addresses. However, now no matter what I do, I cannot connect back the the switch's webconfig. I have set my laptop's NIC to `192.168.254.1` and tried every port on the switch but it fails to connect to the web config.

Can anyone help me with the settings needed to get access back to the webconfig of the switch?

Comment: Consider that you may need to perform a factory reset to re-gain access.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a laptop to have the IP address:

```
IP: 192.168.254.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.252
```

Then plug this laptop into the switch.  This should let you communicate with the switch to change the settings to the way you need it.

Comment: Of course, this should be done after disconnecting the router from the switch, otherwise an IP address conflict will occur.

Comment: Already tried doing this as stated in the question.

Comment: Did you set the subnet to `255.255.255.252`? Were you able to ping or traceroute?